# Using javascript on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook has a special javascript call for setting Fanpage permissions.
Unfortunately, I can't get *any* javascript to work on my page.

Not even a simple alert('bla') in an onclick works.
Am I missing something?

This is the call I want to make:

```
Facebook.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream", ondone, showProfileSelector, [000000]);
```

Comment: post some of your code maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, I think `ondone` should be `"ondone"`.  You have to refer to callbacks by name (as strings) if I recall correctly.

It has to do with FBJS being rewritten before it executes (all that pre-pending random strings/numbers/etc. stuff) and thus the `ondone` function no-longer existing as a callback.

Alternatively, try declaring the `ondone` function inline and see if that helps.

There could be more going on here (if literally no javascript works) but based on what's in your questions that'd be my first guess.

Comment: You're absolutely right.
I took the example code from the API documentation:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook.showPermissionDialog

There the permissions (like "publish_stream") had quotes, but the others didn't. So I thought it had to be omitted.

Comment: Yeah, don't trust the wiki examples.  They're oftentimes outdated.